# How to save a image upload to a folder in magento2?

Tags: magento2, product, jquery, image-upload, save

Created a custom tab on admin product edit page. 
Here added a image upload section. I need to save the uploaded image to a folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using jquery, we can save the image to a folder.

In script, write this code

```
<script>
    function file_up(id)
    {
        var up_id = 'uploadfiles'+id;
        var upremv_id = 'upload'+id;
        var files = document.getElementById(up_id).files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            uploadFile(files[i],up_id,upremv_id);
        }
    }
    function uploadFile(file,up_id,upremv_id){
        var url = "<?php echo $baseurl ?>helloworld/index/upload";
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var fd = new FormData();
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                jQuery('#imgna'+up_id).val(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(xhr.responseText); // handle response.
                jQuery('#'+up_id).remove();
                jQuery('#'+upremv_id).remove();
                var img_va = '<img class="image" src="<?php echo $mediaUrl.'custom/'?>'+xhr.responseText+'">';
                jQuery('#pre'+up_id).html(img_va);
            }
        };
        fd.append('uploaded_file', file);

</script>
```

Then, in your custom controller:

```
Class Upload extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $fileSystem = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
        $mediaPath = $fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
        $media = $mediaPath . 'custom/';

        //  exit;


        $file_name = rand() . $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'];

        if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $media . $file_name)) {
            echo $file_name;
        } else {
            echo "File was not uploaded";
        }
    }
}
```